# Can't save data to file when opening Python script from CMD

Tags: python, debugging, cmd, openpyxl

I have a short script that takes user input and save it to a spreadsheet. When opened from CMD, it seems to run properly, without any errors. However, the data from user input is actually not saved at all. 
Here's the code:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\Users\\sp\\Documents\\testFolder\\testTF.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
while True:  
    print('Enter pairs seprated with colon')
    pairList = input().split(':')
    maxRowNum = sheet.max_row
    sheet.cell(row=maxRowNum + 1, column=1).value = pairList[0]
    sheet.cell(row=maxRowNum + 1, column=2).value = pairList[1]
    wb.save('testTF.xlsx')        
    print('Pair saved\n\n')
```

If opened from File Explorer instead of CMD, the script do save data as intended. But in CMD, it doesn't.
Things I've tried to solve the problem:

1. Run the script in CMD as Admin, instead of normal user
2. Uncheck the "Read Only" property of the parent folder
3. Create a new folder and move the script into it.
4. Uncheck the "Read Only" property of the new parent folder
5. Run the following CMD commands as Admin: "attrib -r +s C:\Users\sp\Documents\testFolder", or "attrib -r -s C:\Users\sp\Documents\testFolder", according to https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-folder-keeps-reverting-to-read-only-on-windows-10/
   None of the upper approaches works. When run in CMD, the script still doesn't save data to spreadsheet. I'm not sure what's wrong and how to solve this. Could anyone help? I really appreciate it.

Comment: Use a singleton, `filepath = 'testTF.xlsx' ;  .load_workbook(filepath) ;  .save(filepath)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading from one path and saving in another.
Try:

```py
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\Users\\sp\\Documents\\testFolder\\testTF.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
while True:  
    print('Enter pairs seprated with colon')
    pairList = input().split(':')
    if len(pairList) < 2:
        break
    maxRowNum = sheet.max_row
    sheet.cell(row=maxRowNum + 1, column=1).value = pairList[0]
    sheet.cell(row=maxRowNum + 1, column=2).value = pairList[1]
    wb.save('C:\\Users\\sp\\Documents\\testFolder\\testTF.xlsx')        
    print('Pair saved\n\n')
```

I just test it and works fine. Maybe you have the excel open, and blocking edition?

Comment: hoo I think I just figured out. You are reading in one location, and saving in another.  see :   wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\Users\\sp\\Documents\\testFolder\\testTF.xlsx') and then  wb.save('testTF.xlsx')

Comment: Try doing wb.save('C:\\Users\\sp\\Documents\\testFolder\\testTF.xlsx')

Comment: No, it doesn't work. In fact, testTF.xlsx and the script are both in the same folder. Both in the cwd.

Comment: I just test it and works fine. Maybe you have the excel open, and blocking edition?

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely right. The cwd changes when running scripts from CMD. Thank you so much for your help. :)

Comment: @wbzy00 You are welcome, please help me voting my answer and also mark it as correct. Thanks